# How to compute the inertial tensor ${\bf{J}} _{\Omega}$?

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

Suppose that $\Omega$ is a body of revolution of the function $y=f(x), a\le x \le b$ around the $x$-axis, where $f(x)>0$ is continuous.

How to compute the inertial tensor ${\bf{J}} _{\Omega}$?

After computing ${\bf{J}} _{\Omega}$, how to solve ${\bf{J}} _{\Omega} \dot w={\bf{J}} _{\Omega} \times w$?

Comment: We could compute the moment of inertia $\Theta$ of this body with respect to the $x$-axis; but the inertial tensor as such is beyond the scope of MSE.